# Generating set for $SL_2(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, lie-groups

Let $F$ be a field and $G = SL_2(F)$. Let us define the following matrices
$$X(b) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad Y(c) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ c & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $b,c\in F$. It a well-known result that these matrices generate $G$ (Lemma 8.1, Ch. XIII in 3rd edition of Lang's Algebra).

After doing some short calculations, I noticed that the set consisting of all matrices $X(b)$ and the matrix $Y(c_0)$ (for some $c_0\in F^\times$) is already a generating set.

Is there some other way to obtain this result?

AYK

---

PS. These are the calculations that I mentioned above:
$$X(-1/x)Y(x)\cdot X(y)\cdot Y(-x)X(1/x) = Y(-x^2y).$$

Comment: Can we make any assumptions about $F$?  Can we say it has characteristic $0$?

Comment: The statement holds in every characteristic. But all arguments are welcome of course..

Comment: wouldn't have expected that.  Good to know.

Comment: By the way: I've added some more generic tags with the hopes of increasing your question's visibility

Comment: @AYK: Are you sure your result is correct. Can you outline the proof?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to include the inverse of $Y(c_0)$ which I've also used in the calculations.

Comment: @AYK: Suppose $F=\mathbb{Q}$. Using, as generators, the set of matrices of the form $X(b)$, together with $Y(2)$, how would you generate $Y(1)$?

Comment: @quasi I've edited the question.

Comment: But $Y(-c_0)$ is  just the inverse of $Y(c_0)$, hence if you have $Y(c_0)$, you get $Y(-c_0)$ for free. So my question remains: How can you generate $Y(1)$ from $Y(2)$ (and the matrices $X(b)$)?

Comment: Ok, I see the edited post -- no need to answer my question.

Comment: @quasi You are right on the 'inverse comment', my bad

Comment: @AYK: Your construction is very nice, and fully answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think, doing "these short calculations" is the best method to obtain this result. 
We may even use only *two* unipotent generators for finite fields, with a few exceptions. A precise statement is given in Dickson's Theorem. For a finite field $F$, and a generator $\lambda$ for $F$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$,
$$
L:=\langle \left( \begin{array}{clcr} 1 & 0\\1 &1 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 1 & \lambda\\0 &1 \end{array} \right) \rangle
$$
is indeed $SL_2(F)$, except when $|F| =9$, in which case $L\cong SL_2(5)$.
For a reference see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=ggYVomvMASYC&pg=PA327&lpg=PA327&dq=dickson's+theorem+generators+of+SL_2(F)&source=bl&ots=r3FPXb6rMA&sig=n_zONiRy6DHyT8SDmHOyk4Xz0FA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid7MP4u5DSAhUMbRQKHSh4BQcQ6AEIWDAH#v=onepage&q=dickson's%20theorem%20generators%20of%20SL_2(F)&f=false).

Comment: I did not assume the field $F$ is finite...

Comment: Yes, but this is the only interesting case left, I think.